# Efficient linq query to return objects when you have a list of object id's

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have a List of all my peronIDs and I'd like to run a Linq query that retrieves the remaining details.

This is my code, but I believe that it checks every item in my People db table against every item in my personID's list which is inefficient:

```
List<int> personIDs = Session["PeopleList"] as List<int>;

var people = (from c in db.People
    where (
    from a in personIDs
    where a == c.PersonID
    select a
    ).Any()
    select c);
```

Is there a more efficient way to run this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
var people = (from c in db.People
              where personIDs.contains(c.id)
              select c).ToList();
```

Comment: This worked with a slight modification: var people = (from c in db.People where personIDs.Contains(c.PersonID) select c).ToList();